# Query Another List for All Data Containing Keyword

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have two lists, one is an asset tracer that contains computer names (table1). The other is a log that contains a description of all the work done on the asset (table2). It contains pc names, an ID, Date and a description. Is there a way to setup a key in table1, that queries table 2, matches the computer names in both tables and either displays the description from table 2 or counts the log entries, with a link. When the user clicks on the link, it takes them to table2.

**Table1**
ID, Device ID, Serial, Log, etc...

**Device Log**
ID,
Device ID,
Description,
Date

EDIT:

I am able to link to the log...
[image]

but I have to manually choose the logs for the pc, in the asset's profile.

[image]

If I have multiple service logs for a device, I have to manually add each log entry, in the asset's properties.

[image]

I'd like Sharepoint to associate the logs, by device, without having to manually add them.

In a database, this would be an INNER JOIN statement. We'd be pulling keys from the Device Log table, that matched the Device ID key and displaying them in the Asset Test table.

Answer (score 1):

You could query another List for all data containing Keyword through using the "**Lookup**" column.

**1.Create a List named "Asset Logs"**

[image]

**2.Create another List named "Asset Tracer"**

- In the "Asset Tracer" List, please create a **Lookup** column named "Computer_ID"
- Select "Asset Logs" under the "**Get information from**" dropdown box and select "Computer_ID" under the "**In this column**" dropdown box.

[image]

**3.When your click on the value of Lookup field, you will see all data containing Keyword from "Asset Logs" List**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's close, but not quite what I was looking for. I have made edits and added detail to my original post.